# Print greater and lesser number in a file

Tags: shell, sorting, awk, grep

```
function greater {
  grep -Eo '[0-9]*' $1 | sort -rn | head -n 1
}

function lesser {
  grep -Eo '\-[0-9]*' $1 | sort -n | head -n 1
}
```

I've made these functions, but the negative numbers are being printed: the first function is ignoring the - sign, so it is showing the greatest number, but it should print the greatest positive. Any ideas on how to solve that?

Sample input:

```
-100 -90 95
10 -20
500 400 300 200 600
```

Sample output:

```
Greater: 600
Lesser: -100
```

(The lesser is working perfectly.)

Comment: `grep -Eo -- '-?[0-9]*' $1 | sort -n | tail -n 1` and `grep -Eo -- '-?[0-9]*' $1 | sort -n | head -n 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest instead of using `grep + sort | head` twice, it would be more efficient to use `gnu awk` and get both `max` and `min` in a single command:

```sh
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '
NR==1 {max=min=$1}
$1 > max {max=$1}
min > $1 {min=$1}
END {print "max=" max, "min=" min}' file

max=600 min=-100
```

Where `file` data is:

```sh
cat file

-100 -90 95
10 -20
500 400 300 200 600
```

Or using any version `awk`:

```sh
tr '[[:blank:]]' '\n' < file |
awk 'NR==1{max=min=$1} $1 > max {max=$1} min > $1 {min=$1} END {print "max=" max, "min=" min}'
```

Comment: I've seen some examples with something similar, but it only works with a single column ($1). But the numbers might be in more than one column, so that code doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hey, I've tried to use the same in a file with only two numbers and the lesser prints nothing. Why?

Comment: `min` needed a correction, please check edited answer

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, you could try following also. Simple explanation would be; using xargs to print all elements in 1 column, then passing it to `awk` as a standard input, where finding the minimum and maximum values by reading whole Input_file at END block of program printing both the values there.

```
xargs -n1 < Input_file | awk 'FNR==1{max=min=$0} max>$0{max=$0} min<$0{min=$0} END{print max,min}'
```

Above reads values from Input_file in case you want to read it from a shell variable then try following(where `var` is shell variable):

```
xargs -n1  <<< "$var" | awk 'FNR==1{max=min=$0} max>$0{max=$0} min<$0{min=$0} END{print max,min}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk alone:

```
awk '
    NR==1 { min=max=$1 }
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i<min) min=$i; if (max<$i) max=$i} }
    END { printf "Greater: %d\nLesser: %d\n", max, min }
' file
Greater: 600
Lesser: -100
```

The printfs with `%d` ensure you'll get numeric output even if the input file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

extending your approach

```
$ tr -s ' ' \\n <file | sort -n | sed -n '1s/.*/min: &/p;$s/.*/max: &/p'

min: -100
max: 600
```